# How do I fully remove the Realtime Kernel?

Tags: kernel, realtime

I'm having an issue uninstalling the Realtime Kernel. I sort of installed it as I misunderstood what it actually is (I confused it with livepatching). I've followed [this guide](https://gist.github.com/chaiyujin/c08e59752c3e238ff3b1a5098322b363) and managed to "disable" it, but it is still set as the default Kernel I believe, as I keep getting this message:

```
The currently running kernel version is 5.15.0-67-generic which is not the expected kernel version │ 
│ 5.15.0-1032-realtime.
```

I cannot find a single piece of documentation! Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you have subscribed to Ubuntu Pro, you may use the command

sudo pro disable realtime-kernel

It worked for me. However make sure that at least one previous kernel is installed in the machine for you to boot into.

Answer (score 0):

Removing any package is usually done with a command like this:

`sudo apt autoremove linux-image-5.15.0-1032-realtime`

This should remove the realtime kernel and revert back to whetever other kernel you used before you install the realtime one.